# CSS3 PIE not working properly in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css3pie, css

I am using CSS3 PIE to render border-image and border-width in IE.  Everything works OK in IE9, but not in IE8.

Strangely, in IE8 the border-image/width works on one DIV (the mailing list at the top right of the page), but not for others (the main content and sidebar, for which no border-image or background-image is showing).

You can see what I mean on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk).

An example of the CSS I am using (in this case for the content DIV) is as follows:

```
div#content .padder {
    border-width:7px;
    -moz-border-image:url('/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/images/background_content.png') 7 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image:url('/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/images/background_content.png') 7 repeat;
    border-image:url('/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/images/background_content.png') 7 repeat;
    -o-border-image:url('/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/images/background_content.png') 7 repeat;
    background-image:url('/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/images/background-main.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

The path to PIE.htc is correct.  Can anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Comment: I have cleared the cache and still see the same issue

Comment: what do you mean by this?  Does the CSS not look correct to you?

Comment: Try setting `position: relative` on the elements that PIE isn't working on.

Comment: Thanks, that's working now.  Strange, it worked in IE7 without the `position:relative`.  Will you add an answer that I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The PIE Specs say:

> ```
> make the target element position:relative, or
> make the ancestor element position:relative and give it a z-index.
> ```

[Known Issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a path relative to the root of your site. It's the only thing that worked for me.

```
behavior: url(/your/path/to/PIE.htc);
```

The following did not work for me

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
behavior: url(../../some/path/to/PIE.htc);
```